# why my code fail to render jQuery template?

Tags: jquery, templates

I am using jQuery tempalte in my project and now i found that a thing not worked i not know what's goes wrong in my code.

can anyone show me where i am goes wrong.

```
 <script id="ajaxresult" type="text/html">
  <li>
                        <h3>
                            <a href="{{= url}}">{{= title}}</a></h3>
                        <p>{{= content}}</p>
                        <div class="url">{{= url}}</div>
                    </li>
    </script>

   var title = $("#txtsrch").val();
    var resp = GetAjaxResponse("/home/blah", { topic: title, pagenum: fpage + 1 });
    $("#ajaxresult").render(JSON.parse(resp)).appendTo("#result ul");
    fpage = fpage + 1;
```

when i try this code i found that i got the error **render is not a function**

can anyone show me where my code have a bug or any other good way i can use to do this thing

Comment: Are you using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/? Because there's no render() function there. Or are you using this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/render ?

Comment: I have no confusion. for testing i use Scottgu's example. and write as same as they write and put the script of them then it's sure to work but it's not. i have no problem i do it using $.template it's hard but work for me thank

Comment: @Moby: “I have no confusion” — glad to hear, although I wish we could say the same.

Comment: Scottgu's post is a year old and the jquery templating functions are still in beta. It is highly likely that the render() function has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, you seem to have pasted HTML code directly into your `<script>` tag, and put your JavaScript outside of the `<script>` tag.

`<script>` tags can only contain JavaScript. At a guess, I’d say your HTML code should look more like this:

```
<ul id="ajaxresult">
    <li>
        <h3><a href="{{= url}}">{{= title}}</a></h3>
        <p>{{= content}}</p>
        <div class="url">{{= url}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I’ve no idea what’s going on in your JavaScript though. As Calum asked in his comment, which part of jQuery are you trying to use?